# in IOS device, first time open the document it shown as blank. Second time preview that it opened. What is the cause of this error. Anyone faced?

Tags: ios, react-native, pdf, view, preview

Preview document in react native:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.1",
"react-native-view-pdf": "^0.11.0",
"react-native-webview": "^11.23.0",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
"react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.4",
```

Any one faced, and what is the cause of this issue?